# SSRS Report Page Orientation

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am creating SSRS reports in Visual Studio but I cannot find out how to set the Page Orientation in my new report from Portrait to Landscape.

I would think this would be in the Report/Report Properties settings but it is not there?

How do I change the Page Orientation from Portrait to Landscape for my new report?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends.

Are you using SSRS 2005 or 2008?

For 2005:
Right-click the white space area of the design surface, choose properties>Layout. Now switch the Page Width/Height values ([21 & 29.7] to [29.7 & 21]). Also, resize the design area to match the layout. i.e. pull the right edge to ~17cm and the bottom edge to about ~24.7cm (for portarit) or right edge to 24.7cm and bottom edge to 21cm (for landscape). For more see [this article](http://lukehayler.com/2009/07/designing-ssrs-reports-that-are-optimized-for-printing/)

For 2008:
Right-click the white space area of the design surface, choose report properties>Page setup>choose landscape/Portrait.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what version you're using because it's a Microsoft product, and Microsoft likes to switch up its options every time it releases a version of something for no good reason.

Comment: @Christine Their business is based on selling mature technology like operating systems and office software that's available for free. In order to keep tricking suits into buying new versions, they have to keep innovating things that don't benefit from innovation.

Answer (score 11):

For Visual studio 2012-
Open the report, In the top navigation, click "Report"

[image]

Goto Report Properties. In the popup, change orientation to what you need it to be.

[image]

Comment: I'm using VS 2017 Community same steps works for me.

Answer (score 7):

For 2012, Finding that report property was a pain for me because I could not see that "wrench" icon on the reporting bar (which can be open by right clicking on an empty area at the header and clicking "Reports".

Once you get there, change the Orientation to landscape.

Answer (score 3):

You have page height/width and interactive height in report properties.
You don't say "Portrait" or "Landscape".

It's not obvious, unfortunately, and this "[Understanding Pagination in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677374.aspx)" only explains indirectly.

Comment: It is a pretty enormously glaring limitation that you can't simply set the page orientation, is it not?

I will try to piece together what to do from the msdn document.  Thanks for your feedback.

Seth

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps -

1. In Main Menu,Click on **Report** in VS2008,
2. Then click on **Report Properties** and
3. in the **Page Setup** tab, Change Orientation to Landscape.