# SSRS Report - Change orientation and margons

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on an SSRS Report and made it in Report Editor. The report looks best in landscape orientation and with smaller margins. I found that the use would have to manually change the setting when printing.

I tried importing the report file into Visual Studio and changing the report setting [StackOverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166184/ssrs-report-page-orientation).

It still does not change work when viewing on the Report Editor. Is there a way to change the settings to print landscape and preferred modified margin settings?

Comment: This should happen automatically if you select the correct orientation in the report properties, so 21cm wide and 29.7cm long for A4 portrait and 21cm long,  29.7cm wide for A4 landscape. The interactive size properties are not the same as the PageSize properties, the interactive size is used when viewing before you print/export.